# How do I get unlimited potion effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and a friend of mine were making a parkour map and we thought it would be handy if there was a way to give the players a unlimited potion effect like jump boost or speed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use command blocks, type in the chat window `/give username 137` with commands enabled (if you're OP), and it will give you a command block. You need to be OP and in creative mode to use these. Place it and right click it, and you will see a text field where you can type

`/effect @p <effect_id> 1000000 [amplifier]`.

This will give the closest player to the block 1000000 seconds of the effect when it's activated with redstone. Effect id's are listed [on this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effects), the first column is the number you'll have to use as `<effect_id>`. The amplifier can be any number between 1 and 255. Normal potions will give either 1 or 2 as amplification. For example, to give the player speed 2, the command has to be

`/effect @p 1 1000000 2`.

or for jump boost 5, you'd get

`/effect @p 8 1000000 5`.

You should watch out that any amplifier value between 128 and 250 will disable jumping, and any value above 251 will decrease jump height.

If you activate the command block with a button, for example, you'll get almost infinitely speed 2.

A command block with time 0, like `/effect @p <effect_id> 0` will disable the effect when powered.

There's more information about command blocks at the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_block).

**1.8 snapshots Edit:**

In the 1.8 snapshots, an extra parameter can be added to the command, which will hide particles when set to true. This will remove the curly particles around your head, whilst still giving the effect. eg. `/effect @p 8 1000000 1 true`.

Also, as Zoweb pointed out, command blocks are now obtained using the command `/give <playername> command_block`, instead of the id 137.

Comment: For everybody curious: 1000000sec = 16666min = 277hours = 11,5days. Not exactly, but a really long time.

Comment: @Ragnagord You have to do __minecraft:command_block__ not just __command_block__

Comment: You can also do __/effect <target> clear__

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms `command_block` works fine for me.

Comment: Play for 11,5 days... Wow.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using a [Beacon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon). Beacons provide ONE of the following powers:

> The five primary powers are:
>
> **Speed**: Increased movement (similar to a potion of swiftness).
>
> **Haste**: Increased mining speed.
>
> **Resistance**: Increased armor rating.
>
> **Jump Boost**: Increased jumping distance and height.
>
> **Strength**: Increased melee damage (similar to a potion of strength).
>
> Level 4 beacon structures can also select a secondary power. This can either be **Regeneration** or a **level II variation of the selected primary power**. When selecting the level II variant, Regeneration is no longer provided by the Beacon.

You can also have  more than one beacon and select a different effect for each one.

Comment: __/effect <target> <effect id> <duration> <amplifier>__

Comment: But still, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You set a command block up, for example, for Speed II you would write

```
/effect <playername> 1 <any valid number>
```

and then you wire it up to a redstone clock, then it will constantly effect and re-effect .

Comment: This doesn't really provide anything new.

Comment: You could just replace the time amount with something over __9999__. This will give an infinite potion effect until the player dies.

Comment: That way you wouldn't have to use a constant redstone clock, which, depending on how powerful someone's computer is, can lag their game.

Answer (score 1):

To give yourself ∞ length of a potion, you could either use a command block or you could just type it in chat (**YOU MUST BE OP**).
Both ways are very similar or exactly the same if you are using *14w11b* or over.

### In Command Block or While Using *14w11b* Or Over

Type in `/effect @p [your effect id - go to` [this link](http://minecraft-helpandinfo.weebly.com/potion-effects-ids.html) `to get the id's] 9999 [strength - remember that 255 (the max) will usually cancel it out so maybe try 100. If you try the effect Jump Boost (8), and you make the strength be 250, this will cancel all jumping (which can actually be quite useful!)]`
Remember that to get a command block in *14w11b* or over, you have to make sure to type in `/give <playername> minecraft:command_block`, not `/give <playername> 137`. Though in below versions you can use `/give <playername> 137`.
[image: Effect in Command Block]

### In Chat While Using Under *14w11b*

Type in `/effect <playername> [effect id] 9999 [strength]`
[image: Effect in Chat]

**Edit**
Now, in 1.8, you can write the name of the potion instead of the ID.

Comment: I think for infinite time it has to be over this magical number 372000 or 37200, not sure, but I am fairly sure that this is right.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Well when I tried it with 9999 and go into my Inventory, and I have given myself an effect, it says I have ∞ length of potion left.

Comment: Hmm, good to know!

Comment: Technically 255 isn't the maximum because it's actually treated as -1. 127 is the maximum.

Answer (score -1):

you have to either type in the chat `/effect (player) (effect id) 1000000` or do the same in a command block (`give (name) 137 64`) but type `effect @p (effect id) 1000000`

Answer (score -1):

so the first thing you do is to make sure that your OP. Then, you press the slash button and it opens the command thing. Then you type in: /effect [*playername*] 1 4000 [*amplifier*]   That gives you infinite speed!!!